# trying to loading a json url with fetch returns an error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, fetch

I'm trying to use the fetch api to get some json data from a url. But I keep getting this error and warning

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=python&location=new+york. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

ERROR TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."
```

Here is the code

```
    url = 'https://'

  fetch(url)
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(getJSON)
  .then((data) => {
      console.log('DATA', data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
  console.log('ERROR', err);
  });

  function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status === 200) {
      return Promise.resolve(response);
  } else {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
  }
  }

  function getJSON(response) {
     return response.json();
   }
```

What is causing this? Any help would be great! tried reading some articles and docs on CORS but I don't really know what to do.

Edit: solved. I had to used JSONP since it was client side code.

Comment: the error says `Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing`, you should add the header.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: what header? and how is it formatted?